# Should Wainscoting have a panel behind the trim or can you add the trim right to the wall

Tags: woodworking, trim, trim-carpentry, wainscoting

I'm looking at adding Wainscoting to a hallway in my home and I'm watching a lot of Youtube videos on how to construct it.  One problematic different I'm seeing is some people believe you should have a panel like 1/2" plywood on the wall before you add the trim and some people say you can just add the trim right to the wall.

I'm sure you CAN add the trim right to the wall but will it be noticeable if you do it that way?  Is it a "cheap" way to do it by not installing a panel first.

This is very close to what i'm looking to do :

[image]

Comment: A wall like drywall/plaster usually does not have enough to hold nails everywhere, only every 16 inches.  Usually does take glue/adhesive everywhere, so think it depends if attaching with nails or glue.

Comment: Adding a panel adds thickness, which is a different look beyond just having a frame on the wall. You have to decide the look you're after.

Comment: Thanks @spuck unfortunately I don't have a frame of reference for how both look so I was hoping for insight into that before I put up one on my wall then have to tear it down to try the other way :)

Comment: If I do a Google image search for "Wainscoting" I see a wide range of wall treatments which look different. When you say you don't have a frame of reference for how "both" look, we don't know which two you are deciding between. Pictures might help.

Comment: [this is very close to what i'm looking to do](https://s.hdnux.com/photos/73/25/41/15554653/4/1200x0.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I have applied wainscotting directly on drywall with construction glue for permanence, temporarily held in place with finishing nails. For this, the wall was **drywall paneling**, that was mudded and smoothly finished.

Sometimes the **substrate panel is part of the finish**, and additional trim is attached on top, for depth. It appears as an insert, but is actually painted backing.

I have also applied wainscotting on furring, in order to better align and straighten the finishing on walls with an uneven surface due to bulging of the drywall or rough unevenness of **concrete foundation walls**.

If you give yourself a backing, at a minimum some strips of plywood, you'll separate the rough work stage to provide support from the more fine work of aligning and patterning. If you find you need lots of strips to support staggered and small panels, a whole sheet might save you lots of work and provide the flexibility to make the task easier.

Always remember when watching youtube videos, that professionals fundamentally work differently from DIYers: it's all a tradeoff between cost, time & pace, skill and whether it's for a paying customer or a critical spouse.

Comment: And they edit out all the practice and oops from the videos.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the best approach is sheet rock first, then wainscotting.  You get better fire protection and noise reduction that way.

When I did my basement a few years ago, I used trim screws into the studs on 16" spacing, no glue.  It looks good and has worked fine so far.

Comment: Sheetrock is usually required for fire rating, but the question seems to be asking about changing a wall in an existing home rather than new construction, so drywall is probably a given.

Comment: Hmm, I can't see any reason to add plywood -over- sheet rock.  Nikolifish, is that what you are asking about?

Comment: The only reason should be to add thickness or have a nailing/screwing base.

Comment: Another reason would be for appearance. Sometimes it doesn't get painted and the wood grain is desired.